# I have a bike with a ratio of 3.11 to 1, how many links do i need in a chain?

Tags: chain

I legit just broke my bike chain riding it. One of the links just snapped and i wanted to replace it with a brand new chain that will hold up better. How many links do i need in that new chain so that it will fit on my bike?

Comment: a [search for "chain length"](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=chain+length) here gives you a number of useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't enough information to determine the chain length from what is given.

You can read one of the many good articles on [how to size a chain](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-length-sizing) on the internet. The chain length depends on the chainring number of teeth, cog number of teeth, chainstay length.

Answer (score 1):

The gear ratio isn't the only factor. The distance between the cranks and the wheel depends on the frame size and geometry. The easiest thing to do is measure the old chain in inches and multiply by 2 (links are half an inch each). Even for a known gear ratio, the exact tooth counts to obtain it can vary.

Answer (score 0):

As you've only given one gear ratio, I'm assuming your bike is a single speed. Chains come in slightly different lengths but this isn't an issue, as you always need to shorten a chain you buy to fit your specific bike. You shorten it with a chain breaker tool, as detailed here - 
http://www.urbanvelo.org/issue10/urbanvelo10_p78-79.html

To join the chain up, thread it onto to chainring and sprocket and take up as much slack as you can. You want it to be short enough so that you when you push the wheel into the horizontal dropouts you can pull the chain taut.

Comment: Can you maybe edit this so it answers the question? "How many links" is the key fact.

Comment: @Mσᶎ it's impossible to give a fixed answer here, as only a ratio has been given to work from. I think the OP is misguided as to what they need to know when buying a new chain

Comment: That's no reason to write a non-answer to a duplicate question. If it can't be answered flag it as such, if it's too vague ask for more information, if there's already an answer point that out.